# Style action bar items differently whether contextual mode is on or not?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-contextmenu

My use case is this: the default action bar displays a blueish background and I want the buttons to turn green on press; on the other hand, the contextual action bar is green and I want the button to turn blue on press. (sort of inverse colours)

- Default action bar:  blue background, green overlay (pressed state)
- Contextual action mode: green background, blue overlay (pressed
  state)

I have already the selectors, and I can set *android:actionBarItemBackground* in my theme to set the drawable for **both** modes. I can also style the close button setting a style in *android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle* and it works fine.

How can I style the other buttons then?

Thanks all,
Gil

Comment: You can't really access those menu items to change the selectors dynamically and I don't remember another theme attribute that you could use instead. One way to solve your problem is to replace the standard menu items with menu items with action views(like a simple `ImageView`) for both the `ActionBar` and `ActionMode` items and set the proper (different) selector on the `ImageView`(you'll also need to handle the interaction with the `ImageView` a.k.a your new `MenuItem`).

Comment: That sounds good, I hadn't thought to replace the buttons with custom action views. I'll code it up to evaluate the maintenance cost, but it  looks alright. Let's see if a more direct solution comes up, otherwise you could write that up in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the views of the `MenuItems` weren't made accessible so you don't have any direct options to access them. One way to alternate the selector for those `MenuItems` is to use `MenuItems` with action views set to `ImageViews` to hold the normal icon and change the selector for those `ImageViews`. An example below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuFirst"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/image_menu_layout"/>
</menu>

<!-- image_menu_layout.xml -->
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       style="@style/Widget.ActionButton"/>
```

The code for the `ActionBar` part:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    // call this for any menu item that you might have
    setUpMenuItem(menu, R.id.menuFirst, false, null);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * This methods set up the MenuItems.
 * 
 * @param menu the menu reference, this would refer either to the menu of the ActionBar or 
 *             the menu of the ActionMode
 * @param itemId the id of the MenuItem which needs work
 * @param onActionMode flag to indicate if we're working on the ActionBar or ActionMode
 * @param modeRef the ActionMode reference(only when the MenuItem belongs to the ActionMode, 
 *                null otherwise)
 */
private void setUpMenuItem(Menu menu, int itemId, final boolean onActionMode,
                           final ActionMode modeRef) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(itemId);
    ImageView itemLayout = (ImageView) menuItem.getActionView();
    itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(onActionMode ? R.drawable.selector_for_actionmode : R
            .drawable.selector_for_actionbar);
    itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // for simplicity, wire up the normal selection callbacks(if possible, 
            // meaning the Activity implements the ActionMode.Callback)
            if (onActionMode) {
                onActionItemClicked(modeRef, menuItem);
            } else {
                onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code for the `ActionMode` part:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actiomode_menu, menu);
    // call this for any menu item that you might have
    setUpMenuItem(menu, R.id.menu_item_from_actionmode, true, mode);
    return true;
}
```

This method will also allow you to avoid the need to handle/keeping the status of the `ActionBar`/`ActionMode` while the `Activity` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the code. You may want to add `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"` to the ImageView (or the equivalent style on API 11+) so the ImageViews look like the action item buttons.

Comment: @Gil I've edited my answer and added the style to the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but you want to use `style="@style/Widget.ActionButton"` instead because your implementation works only on API 11+ (`menuItem.getActionView()` is API 11+, the compatibility version is `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem)`). In my previous comment I pasted the line from my own implementation that uses appcompat